# how to fix navbar to span inside a container - twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/PAj78/

i placed my `navbar` inside a `class="container"`

(move the partition to the left to view the whole container).

you'd see the navbar will go beyond its container.

i played around the bootstrap.css but can't seem to figure out where / which  to adjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.navbar` a full width column with the `.span12` class like this:

```
<div class="navbar span12">
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PAj78/1/)

---

**Explanation**

The elements with the `row` class have a negative `margin-left` by default to compensate the margins on the colums (with the `span` class). The columns have a margin-left to distance themselves from the column before, so the content has some nice spacing. By default bootstrap has 12 columns, so when you make the span of the `navbar` 12 columns it fits exactly within the container. But because it is a column it has the right `margin-left` to compensate for the negative `margin-left` of the `row`. You can see a nice example of the different sized colums [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

Comment: wow! this worked. but would you be so kind to explain to me the logic behind? i just wanna know.

Answer (score 0):

The is a margin:-20px; on ".row, .thumbnails" and on ".row". Overwrite this to prevent your issue from happening.